# How to register custom exception handler in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, exception, laravel-8, httpexception

In Laravel 7 this code works fine. Using `renderable` method also works in laravel 8. But I'm not sure how to register it in laravel 8 after creating a `CustomException` class.

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
            if ($request->expectsJson()) {
                return response('Sorry, validation failed.', 422);
            }
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

Comment: check the document:`https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions`

Comment: I read this documentation. laravel 8 setup a register method. I don't understand how to use it?

Comment: Just every where you need create an object like this: `throw new {your_exception}` but this should be in `try` block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this worked for me.

The register method

```
   public function register()
   {
        $this->renderable(function(Exception $e, $request) {
            return $this->handleException($request, $e);
        });
    }
```

The content of handleException

```
 public function handleException($request, Exception $exception)
 {
     if($exception instanceof RouteNotFoundException) {
        return response('The specified URL cannot be  found.', 404);
     }
 }
```

I hope you will find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

i use this on laravel 8

```
    public function register()
    {

        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {

        });

        $this->renderable(function (Throwable $e) {
            return $this->handleException($e);
        });
    }
```

Source :
https://tony-stark.medium.com/laravel-8-error-handling-upgraded-2021-1ea9afcc2e95

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is a bit confusing to me too. Try this:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (ValidationException $e, $request) {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
           return response('Sorry, validation failed.', 422);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function(\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e, $request) {
        return response()->json([
            'result' => 1,
            'errors' => $e->errors()
        ], 200);
    });
}
```